# Beginner circuit diagram of superposition

Tags: homework

[image]

I get 2amps*(10ohms)/(10+25)ohms-3.5/25=.666-.14amps
Why did I not get .66?

Comment: Please add what you have done to solve the problem, it is much easier for people to find a mistake in the problem than solve it all by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> 2amps*(10ohms)/(10+25)ohms-3.5/25=.666

The right-hand side is correct (\$\dfrac{3.5}{25}\$) but the left one (\$\dfrac{2\cdot10}{10+25}\$) is incorrect, since it should be (\$\dfrac{2\cdot10}{10+15}\$), which does get you to .66 A.

Comment: I meant to say what you put actually. So i'm adding something silly wrong

Comment: Now I understand. I was making actually 2 algebraic errors.

Comment: @user5389726598465 Yes, you just mixed up with the 25\$\Omega\$ being the overall resistance and then adding 10\$\Omega\$ later. Little math mistakes that happen to everyone

Answer (score 0):

The 7 Ohms and 3 Ohms resistors are in series, so find the equivalent resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO1XIq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By doing a source transformation from the 2A supply and 10 Ohms resistor you can get a 20V voltage supply in series with a 10 Ohms resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fffFtU.png)</sup>

Finally, you have two resistors between the two power supply, so just use Ohm's law to find the current. Do notice the 5 Ohms resistors played no role in all this, it can just be ignored (due to the 3.5V power supply).